# How do I prevent the empty instance from appearing in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have `topics_controller.rb` that creates a new `@reply` instance variable for the inline form in the show page.

```
def show
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  @replies = @topic.replies
  @reply = @topic.replies.new
end
```

Now when I loop through `@replies` to display and style existing replies, An empty div appears because of the new instance of the reply in controller.

```
<% @replies.each do |reply| %>
    <div class="reply span8">
      <%= reply.body %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

How do I tackle this and hide the `@topic.replies.new` instance from showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% @replies.each do |reply| %>
  <% next unless reply.body %>
    <div class="reply span8">
      <%= reply.body %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create new instance directly:

```
def show
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  @replies = @topic.replies
  @reply = Reply.new(topic_id: params[:id])
end
```